# VBScript Regex Fill Submatches even when not Required for the Match

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I'm trying to replicate Google calendar's method of creating an appointment from a narrative. I want to enter `5pm Happy Hour for 1 hour` and parse it into, ultimately, an Outlook AppointmentItem.

My problem, I think, is I have a large chunk of optional text at the end. And because it's optional, the regex passes but the submatch doesn't get populated because it isn't required for the match. I want it to populate because I want to use the submatches as my parsing engine.

I have a bunch of test cases in column A (working in Excel, then will move to Outlook), and my code lists out the submatches to the right. This is a representative sample of potential input

```
1. 5pmCST Happy Hour for 1 hour
2. 5pm CST Happy Hour for 1 hour
3. 5pm Happy Hour for 1 hour
4. 5 pm Happy Hour for 1 hour
5. 5 pm CST Happy Hour for 1 hour
6. 5 Happy Hour for 1 hour
7. 5 Happy Hour
8. 5pmCST Happy Hour
9. 5pm CST Happy Hour
10. 5pm Happy Hour
11. 5:00CST Happy Hour for 1 hour
12. 5:00 CST Happy Hour for 1 hour
```

Here's the code that runs the tests

```
Sub testest()

    Dim RegEx As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Dim Matches As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection
    Dim Match As VBScript_RegExp_55.Match
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim SubMatch As Variant
    Dim lCnt As Long
    Dim aPattern(1 To 8) As String

    Set RegEx = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    aPattern(1) = "(1?[0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?)" 'time
    aPattern(2) = "( ?)" 'optional space
    aPattern(3) = "([ap]m)?" 'optional ampm
    aPattern(4) = "( ?)" 'optional space
    aPattern(5) = "([ECMP][DS]T)?" 'optional time zone
    aPattern(6) = "( ?)" 'optional space
    aPattern(7) = "(.+?)" 'event description
    aPattern(8) = "(( for )([1-2]?[0-9](.[0-9]?[0-9])?)( hours?))?" 'optional duration

    RegEx.Pattern = Join(aPattern, vbNullString)
    Debug.Print RegEx.Pattern

    Sheet1.Range("C1").Resize(1000, 100).ClearContents

    For Each rCell In Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Cells
        lCnt = 0
        rCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = RegEx.test(rCell.Text)
        If RegEx.test(rCell.Text) Then
            Set Matches = RegEx.Execute(rCell.Text)

            For Each Match In Matches
                For Each SubMatch In Match.SubMatches
                    lCnt = lCnt + 1
                    rCell.Offset(0, 2 + lCnt).Value = SubMatch
                Next SubMatch
            Next Match
        End If
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

The pattern is

```
(1?[0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?)( ?)([ap]m)?( ?)([ECMP][DS]T)?( ?)(.+?)(( for )([1-2]?[0-9](.[0-9]?[0-9])?)( hours?))?
```

The submatches for #1 are

```
1        2          3        4      5       6       7
5                   pm              CST             H
```

It stops matching at the "H" in Happy Hour because everything starting with the " for " is optional. If I remove the optional part, my pattern becomes

```
(1?[0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?)( ?)([ap]m)?( ?)([ECMP][DS]T)?( ?)(.+?)( for )([1-2]?[0-9](.[0-9]?[0-9])?)( hours?)
```

But #7-#10 don't pass because they don't have a duration. The submmatches for #1 give me what I want though

```
1     2     3     4     5     6     7             8     9     10     11
5           pm          CST         Happy Hour     for  1            hour
```

I want every possible submatch to fill even if VBScript doesn't need it to to make the regex pass. I fear this is just how it works and that I'm trying to get regex to do my parsing work for me. I considered running it through increasingly more restrictive patterns until it doesn't pass, then using the last passing pattern, but that seems kludgy.

Is it possible to get regex to fill those submatches?

Comment: While you can solve this particulair problem with a regexp, I don't think regexps are the solution to replicate Google Calendars behaviour. If you want to do that, you would have to split the string into a list of atoms, get the "group" type of each atom and get the context of the combination of those atoms. With the regexp approach, you'll have an hard time with other formats like _Happy Hour from 17 to 1800_.

Comment: That was my first approach and it seemed like a lot of code. I'm not very strong with regex and thought it might simplify the code. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have assumed each line is all the contents in a single cell.  So I am able to use anchors.
I also don't think you need as many capturing groups as you have.  I set up the regex with:

```
Group 1        Time
Group 2        am/pm
Group 3        Time Zone
Group 4        Description
Group 5        Hours (and fractions of hours)
```

With your data in A2:An, the following routine parses the data into the adjacent columns.  It doesn't matter if a Submatch is "not filled".  You could also fill elements in an array, or whatever else you want to do.  If you want more submatches, you can always either add capturing groups for the optional spaces, or change the relevant non-capturing groups to capturing groups.

Also, since the "for" is optional, I chose to use a lookahead to determine the end of "description".  Description will end with either a \s+for\s+ sequence; or with the "end of line".  Since I have assumed there is only one entry, and one line, per cell, the multiline and global properties are irrelevant.

One has to include spaces before and after "for" so as to avoid problems if that sequence is included in Description.

```
Option Explicit
'set Reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
Sub ParseAppt()
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
    Dim RE As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection
    Dim I As Long
Set R = Range("a2", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
Set RE = New RegExp
With RE
    .Pattern = "((?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9])(?::[0-5]\d)?)\s*([ap]m)?\s*([ECMT][DS]T)?\s*(.*?(?=\s+for\s+|$))(?:\s+for\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*hour)?"
    .IgnoreCase = True
    For Each C In R
        If .Test(C.Text) = True Then
            Set MC = .Execute(C.Text)
            For I = 0 To 4
                C.Offset(0, I + 1) = MC(0).SubMatches(I)
            Next I
        End If
    Next C
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Ron. It's not grabbing the whole time for `12 pm Lunch for 1 hour` - it's only grabbing the 1 for time. I'll work through what the pattern means and likely learn something in the process. I was creating all those captures to ensure that I'd have predictable information in predictable submatches, but yours already does that, so hopefully once I understand the pattern, I'll get it.

Comment: @DickKusleika You're correct.  The fix is a matter of reversing the alternation order so that the regex looks for the hours 10-12 first, then looks for the earlier hours with an optional leading zero.  I will change it in my answer.

Comment: Beautiful. I'm working my way through the regex now and learning a lot. For some reason `a|pm` was matching a or pm rather than a or p then m. I edited that in your answer so please check my edit.

Comment: Your edit is fine.  By the way, there is a relatively inexpensive program -- RegexBuddy -- which I highly recommend for these purposes.